# Can't get submenu to pop up

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to figure out how to get the `.sub_menu` to display when hovering over the main menu.

I know you hide the `.sub_menu` but how do you code when hovering over `<li>` to show sub menu `<ul>`? You would have to target hover for the first `<li>` but then change the `display: none` to however you want the sub menu to look like right?
I can't figure out how to do it.

```css
#navagation{
 float:left;
 width:70%;
 height:100%;border: 1px solid green;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
#btmenu{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
 list-style: none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 height:62px;text-align:center;

 
 

}
ul#btmenu li{ 
padding:0;
margin:0;
display: inline;
height:62px;
width:200px;

}
#btmenu li > a{ height:62px;
line-height:62px;
margin-left:1%;
margin-right:1%;
border: 1px solid green;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
color:#000;
padding-left:1%;
padding-right:1%;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#btmenu > li > a:hover{
background-color:#000;
color:#FFF; 
}
.sub_menu{
display:none;
position:absolute;
width:680px;
background-color:#666;
border: 1px solid red;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#btmenu .sub_menu li{ 
}
.sub_menu li a{display:inline-block;
background-color:#F00;
height:100px;
width:100px;margin:10px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="navagation">
<ul id="btmenu">



<li class="top_quote"><a href="services">services
  <ul class="sub_menu">
    <li class="auto body repair"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="rental & loaner"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="hail damage repair"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="towing"><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li class="glass repair"><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul></a></li>

<li class="top_quote"><a href="locations">locations</a></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="partners">partners</a></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="our work">our work</a></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="contact">contact</a></li>




</ul>
</div><!--navagation-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line to make the sub menu appears when you hover a `li` :

```
#btmenu li:hover ul {display: block}
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/od21qb89/)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the submenu inside the a tag (this can cause problems with the a tags inside the submenu) 
If you put the submenu just after the a tag (as a sibling) then you can act on the `li:hover`

something like:

```
#btmenu > li:hover .sub_menu{
  display: block;
}
```

working example with your snippet:

```css
#navagation{
 float:left;
 width:70%;
 height:100%;border: 1px solid green;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
#btmenu{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
 list-style: none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 height:62px;text-align:center;

 
 

}
ul#btmenu li{ 
padding:0;
margin:0;
display: inline;
height:62px;
width:200px;

}
#btmenu li > a{ height:62px;
line-height:62px;
margin-left:1%;
margin-right:1%;
border: 1px solid green;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
color:#000;
padding-left:1%;
padding-right:1%;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#btmenu > li > a:hover{
background-color:#000;
color:#FFF; 
}
.sub_menu{
display:none;
position:absolute;
width:680px;
background-color:#666;
border: 1px solid red;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#btmenu .sub_menu li{ 
}
.sub_menu li a{display:inline-block;
background-color:#F00;
height:100px;
width:100px;margin:10px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
}

#btmenu > li:hover .sub_menu{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navagation">
<ul id="btmenu">



<li class="top_quote">
  <a href="services">services</a>
  <ul class="sub_menu">
    <li class="auto body repair"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="rental & loaner"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="hail damage repair"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="towing"><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li class="glass repair"><a href="#">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="top_quote"><a href="locations">locations</a></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="partners">partners</a></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="our work">our work</a></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="contact">contact</a></li>




</ul>
</div><!--navagation-->
```